# In Jenkins, how to run a script continuously in parallel until a build is complete?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

While one command is waiting for something I would like to see in logs periodical response from another command to understand what's going on in background. And when the first command is done, the second one (background monitoring) should automatically stop working.

Is this possible to do in Jenkinsfile?

Comment: Inside a `parallel` block, one can do its thing and set an exit flag for the other task?

Comment: hmm.. makes sense